# Confusion over change of sign during parity transformations

Tags: symmetry, vectors, conventions, parity

In his lecture on symmetry in physical law, https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_52.html, (under the polar and axial vectors sub-section), Feynman writes: “ Now if the law of reflection symmetry is right in physics, then it must be true that the equations [of physics] must be so designed that if we change the sign of each axial vector and each cross-product of vectors, which would be what corresponds to reflection, nothing will happen. For instance, when we write a formula which says that the angular momentum is L=r×p, that equation is all right, because if we change to a left-hand coordinate system, we change the sign of L, but p and r do not change; the cross-product sign is changed, since we must change from a right-hand rule to a left-hand rule.”

There are several things that confuse me here. Firstly, it was my understanding that axial vectors (pseudovectors) are supposed not to change sign during parity transformations whereas Feynman implies that they do change sign. Where am I going wrong? (EDIT: I have worked out the answer to this question myself- see the comments section)

Secondly, surely if we change from a right-hand rule to a left-hand rule when we carry out a parity transformation, the cross-product will not change sign in the mirrored space. This is also contrary to what Feynman writes?

The above confusion also made me question why a right hand rule shouldn’t always be mirrored to a left hand rule during a parity transformation, given that the laws of physics (besides the weak force) are all entirely mirrored?

Comment: I believe that the answer to my first query lies in that Feynman is referring to the change in sign of the axial vectors from the perspective of the mirrored coordinate system since, while the axial vector itself does not change relative to the original coordinate system, the fact that the entire mirrored space undergoes a parity transformation means that it is inverted relative to that axial vector which, thus, in the mirrored coordinates, changes sign, despite not changing direction relative to the original, non-mirrored space.

Comment: I would still appreciate answers to my other queries please.